# finding a palindrome using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, palindrome

i have this problem that i'm having troubles to solve.
the user needs to enter 15 numbers (whole numbers) and i need to check if there's a palindrome.

if there are more then one i must take the longest one, and if there are more then one with the same size, i must take the one whose index comes first. i.e:

```
Input:
1 2 1 3 5 6 7 8 9 4 5 6 8 9 8
Output:
Palindrome Found: 121
Input:
1 2 1 3 3 1 6 4 8 7 9 5 4 8 6
Output:
1 3 3 1
```

that is my code at the moment:
when i run it, the values of k and array1[k], seems to be an error. i've gor them back with the value 5373952.
even if there is a palindrome it call back that the palindrome was not found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double arr[15]={0};
    int array1[15];
    int i,j,k=0;

    for (i=0; i<15; i++) // the program is asking for 15 numbers from the user.
    {
        scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);
        if ((arr[i]-(int)arr[i])!= 0)// if the number is not a whole number, the program will stop immediately.
        {
            printf("Error \n");
            return (0);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        for(j=14; j>=i; j--) // going back-wards to the start. checking at each point for a match.
        {
            if ((int)arr[i]==(int)arr[j])
            {
                array1[k]=(int)arr[j];
                i++;
                j--;
                k++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( (int)arr[j] == array1[k] )
    {
        printf("Palindrome Found:%d \n", array1[k]);
    }
    else
    {  
        printf("Palindrome Not Found \n");
    }

    return (0);

}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is your Problem? What goes wrong?

Comment: If you're after a smarter algorithm, you could implement with a stack. That is not an SO question. If you've got an error, tell us what that is.

Comment: Why are you inputting to `double` when you discard them if they are not whole numbers?

Comment: i input them as a double in order to make sure that im not getting nummbers with decimal point. if the user does gives me a number with decimal point it will call out ERORR.

Comment: The question isn't about numbers, but numeric strings. Try `char s[16]; scanf("%15s", s);` and on from there *(hint `isdigit()`)*. I'd like to write your project, but it's not mine.

Answer (score 0):

The number must be between 0 and 9, or can be bigger? For example

```
1 2 13 22 16 4
```

Anyway, it's wise to work with the input as a string.

Comment: i need to work with arrays only...
and yes, i asume that the numbers are all between 0-9

Comment: A string is also an array of characters. If the numbers are limited to 0-9, it doesn't matter. However, if the numbers consist of more than 1 digit, than a string is much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arr[15]={0};
    int i,j;
    int start, end, max_len = 1;

    for (i=0; i<15; i++){
        if(1 != scanf("%1d", &arr[i]) || arr[i] < 0){
            printf("input error\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 15 - max_len; ++i){
        for(j=i+max_len; j<15; ++j){
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                int found = 1;
                int s, e, len = j - i + 1;
                for(s=i, e=j; s < e; ++s, --e){
                    if(arr[s] != arr[e]){
                        found = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(found && max_len < len){
                    start = i;
                    end   = j;
                    max_len = len;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(max_len == 1)
        printf("Palindrome Not Found \n");
    else {
        printf("Palindrome Found:");
        for(i=start; i<=end; ++i)
            printf(" %d", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```